# Iterating over the contents of an Option, or over a specific value

Tags: rust

Let's say that we have the following C-code (assume that srclen == dstlen and the length is divisible by 64).

```
void stream(uint8_t *dst, uint8_t *src, size_t dstlen) {
    int i;
    uint8_t block[64];
    while (dstlen > 64) {
        some_function_that_initializes_block(block);
        for (i=0; i<64; i++) {
            dst[i] = ((src != NULL)?src[i]:0) ^ block[i];
        }
        dst += 64;
        dstlen -= 64;
        if (src != NULL) { src += 64; }
    }
}
```

That is a function that takes a source and a destination and xors source with some value that
the function computes. When source is set to a NULL-pointer dst is just the computed value.

In rust it is quite simple to do this when src cannot be null, we can do something like:

```
fn stream(dst: &mut [u8], src: &[u8]) {
    let mut block = [0u8, ..64];
    for (dstchunk, srcchunk) in dst.chunks_mut(64).zip(src.chunks(64)) {
        some_function_that_initializes_block(block);
        for (d, (&s, &b)) in dstchunk.iter_mut().zip(srcchunk.iter().zip(block.iter())) {
            *d = s ^ b;
        }
    }
}
```

However let us assume that we want to be able to mimic the original C-function. Then we would like to do something like:

```
fn stream(dst: &mut[u8], osrc: Option<&[u8]>) {
    let srciter = match osrc {
        None => repeat(0),
        Some(src) => src.iter()
    };
    // the rest of the code as above
}
```

Alas, this won't work since repeat(0) and src.iter() have different types. However it doesn't seem possible to solve this by using a trait object since we get a compiler error saying `cannot convert to a trait object because trait 'core::iter::Iterator' is not object safe.`  (also there is no function in the standard library that chunks an iterator).

Is there any nice way to solve this, or should I just duplicate the code in each arm of the match statement?

Comment: Your loop condition in C version looks strange. `srclen` is never modified in the loop, making it infinite if it is initially greater than 64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of repeating the code in each arm, you can call a generic inner function:

```
fn stream(dst: &mut[u8], osrc: Option<&[u8]>) {
    fn inner<T>(dst: &mut[u8], srciter: T) where T: Iterator<u8> {
        let mut block = [0u8, ..64];
        //...
    }

    match osrc {
        None => inner(dst, repeat(0)),
        Some(src) => inner(dst, src.iter().map(|a| *a))
    }
}
```

Note the additional `map` to make both iterators compatible (`Iterator<u8>`).

---

As you mentioned, `Iterator` doesn't have a built-in way to do chunking. Let's incorporate Vladimir's solution and use an iterator over chunks:

```
fn stream(dst: &mut[u8], osrc: Option<&[u8]>) {
    const CHUNK_SIZE: uint = 64;

    fn inner<'a, T>(dst: &mut[u8], srciter: T) where T: Iterator<&'a [u8]> {
        let mut block = [0u8, ..CHUNK_SIZE];
        for (dstchunk, srcchunk) in dst.chunks_mut(CHUNK_SIZE).zip(srciter) {
            some_function_that_initializes_block(block);
            for (d, (&s, &b)) in dstchunk.iter_mut().zip(srcchunk.iter().zip(block.iter())) {
                *d = s ^ b;
            }
        }
    }

    static ZEROES: &'static [u8] = &[0u8, ..CHUNK_SIZE];

    match osrc {
        None => inner(dst, repeat(ZEROES)),
        Some(src) => inner(dst, src.chunks(CHUNK_SIZE))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. Just a small question. What is the difference between writing `fn inner<'a, T>(dst: &mut[u8], srciter: T) where T: Iterator<&'a [u8]>` and writing `fn inner<'a, T: Iterator<&'a [u8]>>(dst: &mut [u8], srciter: T)`?

Comment: There is no difference. They mean exactly the same thing. `where` syntax was introduced because it often leads to more understandable code and it also allows specifying bounds on associated types.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it is impossible to use different iterators directly or with trait objects (which have recently been changed to disallow instantiation of trait objects with inappropriate methods i.e. ones which use `Self` type in their signature). There is a workaround for your particular case, however. Just use enums:

```
fn stream(dst: &mut [u8], src: Option<&[u8]>) {
    static EMPTY: &'static [u8] = &[0u8, ..64];  // '

    enum DifferentIterators<'a> {  // ' 
        FromSlice(std::slice::Chunks<'a, u8>),  // '
        FromRepeat(std::iter::Repeat<&'a [u8]>) // '
    }

    impl<'a> Iterator<&'a [u8]> for DifferentIterators<'a> {  // '
        #[inline]
        fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a [u8]> { // '
            match *self {
                FromSlice(ref mut i) => i.next(),
                FromRepeat(ref mut i) => i.next()
            }
        }
    }

    let srciter = match src {
        None => FromRepeat(repeat(EMPTY)),
        Some(src) => FromSlice(src.chunks(64))
    };

    let mut block = [0u8, ..64];
    for (dstchunk, srcchunk) in dst.chunks_mut(64).zip(srciter) {
        some_function_that_initializes_block(block);
        for (d, (&s, &b)) in dstchunk.iter_mut().zip(srcchunk.iter().zip(block.iter())) {
            *d = s ^ b;
        }
    }
}
```

This is a lot of code, unfortunately, but in return it is more safe and less error-prone than the C version. It is also possible to optimize it in order not to require `repeat()` at all:

```
fn stream(dst: &mut [u8], src: Option<&[u8]>) {
    static EMPTY: &'static [u8] = &[0u8, ..64];  // '

    enum DifferentIterators<'a> {  // ' 
        FromSlice(std::slice::Chunks<'a, u8>),  // '
        AlwaysZeros
    }

    impl<'a> Iterator<&'a [u8]> for DifferentIterators<'a> {  // '
        #[inline]
        fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a [u8]> { // '
            match *self {
                FromSlice(ref mut i) => i.next(),
                AlwaysZeros => Some(STATIC),
            }
        }
    }

    let srciter = match src {
        None => AlwaysZeros,
        Some(src) => FromSlice(src.chunks(64))
    };

    let mut block = [0u8, ..64];
    for (dstchunk, srcchunk) in dst.chunks_mut(64).zip(srciter) {
        some_function_that_initializes_block(block);
        for (d, (&s, &b)) in dstchunk.iter_mut().zip(srcchunk.iter().zip(block.iter())) {
            *d = s ^ b;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works. I wish I could accept both of the answers but I accepted the other one because it led to a bit less code.